# Send and Retrieve high score from local storage

Tags: javascript, get, set, local, store

here is a link to the game
https://jsfiddle.net/ab4gaf15/5/
you have to sign up and log in in order to play, that much I've got working
I just need to know what the function would look like so the score the player gets from the game is sent to local storage and then retrieved from local storage to a table that holds the score of all players.

```
  /* This function is called when a logged in user 
    plays the game and gets a score */
function updateScore(newScore) {
    //Get the JavaScript object that holds the data for the logged in user
    var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);

    //Update the user object with the new top score
    /* NOTE YOU NEED TO CHANGE THIS CODE TO CHECK TO SEE IF THE NEW SCORE
        IS GREATER THAN THE OLD SCORE */
    usrObj.topscore = newScore;

    //Put the user data back into local storage.
    localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
}


/* Loads the rankings table.
    This function should be called when the page containing the rankings table loads */
function showRankingsTable() {
    //Get a reference to the div that will hold the rankings table.
    var rankingDiv = document.getElementById("RankingsTable");

    //Create a variable that will hold the HTML for the rankings table
    var htmlStr = "";

    //Add a heading 
    htmlStr += "<h1>Rankings Table</h1>";

    //Add the table tag
    htmlStr += "<table>";

    //Work through all of the keys in local storage
    for (var key in localStorage) {
        //All of the keys should point to user data except loggedInUser
        if (key !== "loggedInUser") {
            //Extract object containing user data

            //Extract user name and top score
            htmlStr += "David";
            //Add a table row to the HTML string.
        }
    }

    //Finish off the table
    htmlStr += "</table>";
```

Comment: localStorage is only available client side so other peoples rankings wouldn't be available to a user. You'd need to pull the data from a server for people to see each others rankings.

Comment: how can I do it for just my own score then?

Answer (score 1):

You've actually got all the pieces you need in your example

this is an example of setting a value in localStorage...

```
localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] = JSON.stringify(usrObj);
```

and this is an example of retrieving that value again...

```
var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);
```

To display the current users score in the table would look like this...

```
/* Loads the rankings table.
    This function should be called when the page containing the rankings table loads */
function showRankingsTable() {
    //Get a reference to the div that will hold the rankings table.
    var rankingDiv = document.getElementById("RankingsTable");

    //Create a variable that will hold the HTML for the rankings table
    var htmlStr = "";

    //Add a heading
    htmlStr += "<h1>Rankings Table</h1>";

    //Add the table tag
    htmlStr += "<table>";

    //Work through all of the keys in local storage
    if (typeof localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser] !== 'undefined') {

        usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUser]);
        htmlStr += "<tr>";
            htmlStr += "<td>";
                htmlStr += usrObj;
            htmlStr += "<td>";
                htmlStr += "<td>";
                    htmlStr += localStorage.loggedInUser;
                htmlStr += "<td>";
            htmlStr += "</td>";
        htmlStr += "</tr>";

    }

    //Finish off the table
    htmlStr += "</table>";
}
```